# Is tempered distribution a distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis

In [Distribution Theoryand Fundamental Solutions of Differential Operators](http://www.bcamath.org/documentos_public/archivos/personal/tesis/GAL_Daniel_Eceizabarrena_-_Distribution_Theory_and_Fundamental_Solutions_of_Differential_Operators.pdf) we can find following theorem with proof.

> [image]

I think this proof is not valid starting from blue sentence.

To show that $f\in\mathcal{D}'$ one needs to check the second condition.

> [image]

Since $f\in\mathcal{S}'$, we've know that following condition (2) holds,

> [image]

Now I think that we focus on showing that (2.11.2)$\implies$(1.9.2).

However the author assumes the blue sentence and uses

> [image]

which is helpless because we already assumed that we have convergence in $\mathcal{S}$.

Another point is that following theorem states that

> [image]

which tell us that that there can be a function $f$ that could be convergent in $\mathcal{S}$ but not in $\mathcal{D}$.

How to show that **(2.11.2)$\implies$(1.9.2)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have misread.  The sentence in blue asserts that $\phi_n \to 0$ in the space $\mathcal{D}$ of test functions, not in $\mathcal{S}$.  By proposition 2.7, it must converge in $\mathcal{S}$, and it is not hard to show that $\phi_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}$.

Note that we have that $T$ is in $\mathcal{S}'$, and we want to show it is in $\mathcal{D}'$.  Thus, it is sufficient to show that $T(\phi_n) \to 0$ for any sequence $\phi_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}$.  The point is that we can use the containment $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{S}$ to do this.

Your comment on the last passage you cite is unclear, since a function $f \in \mathcal{S}$ cannot be said to converge in $\mathcal{S}$.  However, it is true that there are sequences in $\mathcal{S} \cap \mathcal{D}$ which converge in $\mathcal{S}$ but not in $\mathcal{D}$.  For example, if $\psi$ be a $C^\infty_0$ function supported on the ball of radius $2$ which is equal to $1$ on the ball of radius $1$, then the sequence
$$\phi_n(x) = e^{-x^2} \psi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
converges to $e^{-x^2}$ in $\mathcal{S}$, but is divergent in $\mathcal{D}$ (since $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{supp} \phi_n = \mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Hello. I can see that if $\varPhi_n\rightarrow0$ in $\mathcal{D}$ then $\varPhi_n\rightarrow0$ in $\mathcal{S}$. My problem is that in that way I'm not sure we're checking every sequence required by condition (1.9.2) but only some of them.

Comment: Note that we have two distinct definitions of convergence here: in $\mathcal{D}$  - (1.15) and in $\mathcal{S}$ - (2.5)

Comment: @AndrzejGolonka Yes, that is true.  But, by the theorem, any sequence that converges according to (1.15) will also converge according to (2.5).  Note that we are checking every sequence converging to $0$ in $\mathcal{D}$: it's just that each one of these sequences *also* converges to $0$ in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: But is there a 1-1 relation between them? Because we need to check the condition for  every $\varPhi_n\rightarrow0$ that is convergent in $\mathcal{S}$, not for those $\varPhi_n\rightarrow0$ that are convergent in $\mathcal{D}$ and thus also in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @AndrzejGolonka The point is that we do *not* need to check the condition for sequences in $\mathcal{S}$.  We begin by assuming $f \in \mathcal{S}'$, so the condition must hold true.  We want to show $f \in \mathcal{D}'$, so we need to work with arbitrary sequences in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your help!